# MySQL Get Column Name(s) that Matched the WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a VIEW with 4 columns that I'm basically using as a Full-Text search. The user enters a string into a textbox and it queries the VIEW like so:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_clients WHERE
col1 = "'%".$userInput."%'"
OR col2 = "'%".$userInput."%'"
OR col3 = "'%".$userInput."%'"
OR col4 = "'%".$userInput."%'"
```

My results are returned correctly, but is there a way to determine which columns contained the search term? Either via MySQL or PHP?

Comment: This isn't fulltext search. This is old school search with incorrect syntax.

Comment: It's a bit odd that the column values would contain leading and trailing '%' characters. It seriously looks like the '=' comparison operator is intended to actually be a LIKE comparison operator. And I'll also include the requisite note that this appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly in MySQL, but there are hideously ugly hacks:

```
SELECT col1, (col1 LIKE '%$userinput%') AS found_in_col1,
     col2, (col2 LIKE '%$userinput%') AS found_in_col2, 
     etc...
etc...
WHERE ...
```

in php, it'd be a matter of looping over the fields in the result set and doing a `strpos()` check. Either way... ugly.

Comment: Yeah, I like that.  Sometimes, dirty is the only way to go.

Comment: I think you could wrap it in a `CASE...WHEN...END` so that you have only one column.

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT 
      *,
      CONCAT_WS(',',
        IF(col1 = "'%".$userInput."%'",'col1',NULL),
        IF(col2 = "'%".$userInput."%'",'col2',NULL),
        IF(col3 = "'%".$userInput."%'",'col3',NULL),
        IF(col4 = "'%".$userInput."%'",'col4',NULL)) as colmatches
   FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more ugly method: using "case" or "if" in select query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1='%value%' THEN 'col1' WHEN col2='%value%' THEN 'col2' END as found_column
FROM ....
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(v.col1 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%'),0) AS col1_match
     , IFNULL(v.col2 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%'),0) AS col2_match
     , IFNULL(v.col3 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%'),0) AS col3_match
     , IFNULL(v.col4 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%'),0) AS col4_match
     , v.*
  FROM vw_clients v
 WHERE v.col1 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%') = 1
    OR v.col2 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%') = 1
    OR v.col3 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%') = 1
    OR v.col4 LIKE CONCAT('%','$userInput','%') = 1
```

---

N.B. This construct is vulnerable to SQL Injection; it's depending on `$userInput` not containing SQL constructs. e.g.

```
$userInput = "foo')=1 OR '1' LIKE CONCAT('1";
```